# Nginx Performance when we are logging request and response

Tags: apache, nginx

We have `exposed our API to multiple clients` and we want to `track all requests from clients` and keep it for analysis purpose. If client asks for response later, we can easily provide response also.

1. Is it good practice to log request and response at nginx level?
2. Will there be any impact on nginx performance as it is logging all data?
3. Can we do logging asynchronously in nginx? If we can, can you please provide reference link?
4. If nginx is not good choice to log, what can be best way to perform logging?

Can someone please help me on this?

Thank you